# Linq2Sql FROM XSD

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, xsd

I have a scenario where I define the XSD first, then generate the cs files from these XSD (using xsd.exe). I need to take this 2 steps furthur by generating the dbml from these and then calling CreateDatabase() on that dbml).

So the question is, does anyone have an idea how to create dbml from either an XSD or a cs file?

Thanks
Ash